# How to call a function inside of another function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm making my own Online Store with PHP and MySQLi. Basically I have a section where users can see all the Brands of the Store and the number of each items which exists in table also appear. Something like this:

[image]

In order to print this data on screen, I did this:

```
<?php 
    function get_brands(){
        $get_brands = "select * from brands";
        $run_brands = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],$get_brands);
        while($row_brands = mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)){
            $brand_id = $row_brands['brand_id'];
            $brand_title = $row_brands['brand_title'];
            echo " <li><a href='brands.php?brand_id=$brand_id'><span class='pull-right'><strong>(number items within this brand)</span>$brand_title</strong></a></li>";
        }
    }
?>
```

So because I have two tables at my db, I need to call another function within this function to count number of items from the other table.

One of the tables is called `products` which contains brand name field and the other one is `brands` as the images shows:

[image]

So how to do this ? Any idea please

Comment: This is solved by one query with `JOIN` and `COUNT`

Comment: you can just simply call `function2()` inside of `get_brands()`?

Comment: We need to know the table structure of both tables to help out further. You can follow @u_mulder's suggestion of joining and counting the other table (Which then you can simple reference as a field in your while loop), or you can post more information so we can help further.

Comment: "I need to call another function within this function to count number of items from the other table" - it is highly unlikely that this is a requirement, and its very innefficient. Why can you not just run a query with a join?

Comment: use query like this
`select b.*, count(p.product_id) as product_count from brands b left join products p on p.brand_id = b.brand_id group by b.brand_id` get the value like this `$row_brands['product_count']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of your while loop, you will have to make another database call to get the total number of items with that brand ID. So the function that prints stuff out should look like this:

```
<?php 
function get_brands(){
    $get_brands = "select * from brands";
    $run_brands = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],$get_brands);

    while($row_brands = mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)){
        $brand_id = $row_brands['brand_id'];
        $brand_title = $row_brands['brand_title'];

        $totalNumberOfProductsQuery = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE brand_id = " . $brand_id;
        $brandProducts = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con', $totalNumberOfProductsQuery);
        $totalProductsForBrand = mysqli_num_rows($brandProducts);

        echo " <li><a href='brands.php?brand_id=$brand_id'><span class='pull-right'><strong>$totalProductsForBrand</span>$brand_title</strong></a></li>";
    }
}
```

Don't know if copying and pasting this will work, but you get the idea I hope.

Answer (score 0):

create a new function like this

```
function count_brands($tableName, $brandId){
    $brandsNum = "select count(*) from " . $tableName ." Where product_id = ". $brandId ." ";
    $count = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],$brandsNum);
    return $count;
}
```

and call it inside your current function simply like this .

```
function get_brands(){
    $get_brands = "select * from brands";
    $run_brands = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],$get_brands);
    while($row_brands = mysqli_fetch_array($run_brands)){
        $brand_id = $row_brands['brand_id'];
        $brand_title = $row_brands['brand_title'];

        echo "
            <li><a href='brands.php?brand_id=$brand_id'><span class='pull-right'><strong> ". count_brands('brands', $brand_id) . "</span>$brand_title</strong></a></li>
        ";
    }
}
```

assuming this two functions in the same file 
   and if those functions inside a class . so you refers to it like this

```
$this->count_brands();
```

Comment: You didn't understand the question, I want to count all the products from products table while get_brands() function is returning a custom brand name.

Comment: `<li><a href='brands.php?brand_id=$brand_id'><span class='pull-right'><strong>(number of products which has this brand name)</span>$brand_title</strong></a></li>`

Comment: take a look at `(number of products which has this brand name)` in the above statement.

Comment: @thiwrouweach so you have two tables brands and products . rights ?